# Modifying MySQL Where Statement Based on Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Using an array like this:

```
$data = array
     (
       'host' => 1,
       'country' => 'fr',
     )
```

I would like to create a MySQL query that uses the values of the array to form its WHERE clause like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE host = 1 and country = 'fr'
```

How can I generate this query string to use with MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$where = '';

foreach( $data as $k => $v ) {
    if( !empty( $where ) )
        $where .= ' AND ';

    $where .= sprintf( "`%s` = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string( $k ), mysql_real_escape_string( $v ) );
}

mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE $where" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please please please don't build SQL statements with embedded data.  Look here: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html